# Pie-in-pie (Donut) charts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, charts, google-visualization

Can someone suggest me any good plugin on how to create graphs similar to those presented in the images bellow? If someone knows a way to do that with Google Charts that would be the optimal.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Chart Tools | Pie Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/pie_charts.html) page shows an example of a concentric pie chart:

[image]

According to that page:

> **pc**
>
> A concentric pie chart.
>
> Supply two or more data series.

Is that along the lines of what you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately the image chart API is now deprecated and there does not appear to be support for concentric pie charts in the Charts API. A feature request has been raised: http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=786